# Some js files have temporary string at the end

Tags: joomla-3.x, jquery

I have some js files which have temporary string at the end, the problem is that jQuery is already loaded before so it cause issues.

```
<script src="www.example.com/media/system/js/core.js?c053e5a315af285403fcc2192089780b" type="text/javascript"></script>
<!--[if lt IE 9]><script src="www.example.com/media/system/js/polyfill.event.js?c053e5a315af285403fcc2192089780b" type="text/javascript"></script><![endif]-->
<script src="www.example.com/media/system/js/keepalive.js?c053e5a315af285403fcc2192089780b" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="www.example.com/media/jui/js/jquery.min.js?c053e5a315af285403fcc2192089780b" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="www.example.com/media/jui/js/jquery-noconflict.js?c053e5a315af285403fcc2192089780b" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="www.example.com/media/jui/js/jquery-migrate.min.js?c053e5a315af285403fcc2192089780b" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

My template have rules to remove the jquery loaded above, but it can't work :

```
// Rules to remove predefined jQuery and Bootstrap and MooTools More
GKParser::$customRules['/<script src="(.*?)media\/jui\/js\/jquery.min.js" type="text\/javascript"><\/script>/mi'] = '';
GKParser::$customRules['/<script src="(.*?)media\/jui\/js\/jquery-noconflict.js" type="text\/javascript"><\/script>/mi'] = '';
GKParser::$customRules['/<script src="(.*?)media\/jui\/js\/bootstrap.min.js" type="text\/javascript"><\/script>/mi'] = '';
```

What thing can add this string at the end of some js files ?

Thanks by advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The strings are added by Joomla: [method_addScriptVersion](https://api.joomla.org/cms-3/classes/JDocument.html#method_addScriptVersion).
You may find this plugin usefull to remove scribts etc.: [kubik-rubik, jcc-js-css-control](https://joomla-extensions.kubik-rubik.de/downloads/jcc-js-css-control/joomla-3)

Comment: Issue in older Joomla versions [link](https://github.com/joomla/joomla-cms/issues/12828)

Comment: I have installed this plugin and configured it, it make the job. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Most likely a plugin would do that, such as JCH Optimize. The strings are added at the end to ensure that the browsers always grab a fresh version of these files (and not use a cached version). Check JCH Optimize (and any other JS/CSS compression/optimization extension installed that you have) on how to disable that.

Additionally, some templates may also do the same thing, also check your template settings.

If you're still not sure what's causing it, then do the following:

- Switch to a different template and see if the problem is no more. If the problem disappears, then the problem is in your template.
- Disable your plugins one by one (starting with the one with the highest ID) until the problem is no more.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, i don't use JCH Optimize. I have checked in all plugins and i didn't found a plugin like JCH Optimize. I have switched to protostar as default template but it adds too these strings at the end of files.

Comment: Then there must be another plugin doing this. Disable your plugins one by one until you find the culprit.

Comment: I have just done a clean install of Joomla! 3.7.5, without installing anything. And for all js and css, it adds string at the end. Something has changed into Joomla! but i don't what

Comment: By disabling all plugins enabled, it still does the same thing. This behaviour has changed since J! 3.6.x or maybe J!3.7.x